# New to macintosh and want to port some of my Python code. What would be the equivalent of Windows Win32api?

Tags: python, macos, winapi, osx-snow-leopard

I have a couple of scripts that rely heavily on the win32api/win32con wrappers for automation tasks. What is the equivalent for macintosh systems. I'm looking for a way to control things such as spawning programs, sending virtual keys, virtual mouseclicks/positions, etc..

Comment: Have you investigated http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: This Q is way too broad. You need to ask something specific. Start by giving us a concrete example where you need to use win32 rather than standard python libs.

Comment: The complete answer to your question would include system calls, GUI interaction, `fcntl`, `ioctl`, etc., etc. So you need to be more specific. The good news is that a lot of things can be done on unix systems without going through the kinds of hoops that Windows requires.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could roll your own, but perfectly good platform independent tools exist to do this already.

Check out sikuli http://sikuli.org/

Comment: It is as far as I know. I believe there were some experiments to use cpython, but I haven't checked their status for a while